# www/non-www .htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two sites on my hosting account:

business.com
bookgroup.com

I want business.com to always be served with https.  I don't have an SSL cert for bookgroup.com so it can stay http.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^business\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and this works perfectly for business.com. It also works for bookgroup.com. But when I do

http://www.bookgroup.com

It redirects to https://www.bookgroup.com.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: This rule will only work for `business.com` due to first `RewriteCond`. You may have some other rule/code doing this. Also test your browser cache once.

Comment: @anubhava Please make your comment (browser cache) an answer so I can give you the points; that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will only work for `business.com` domain due to first `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^business\.com [NC]
```

You may have some other rule/code doing this or it is happening due to old browser cache.

There are several ways to verify:

1. Completely clear your browser cache
2. Use command line tools such as curl/wget to test it
3. Use Incognito mode in Chrome with cache disabled
4. Test in a different browser

Comment: Another testing method I used successfully - test in a different browser.